# Post to Web Service from ASP, from Remote Server

Tags: web-services, http, asp-classic

I'm trying to Post Data to a Web Service, from ASP (VBScript), using the CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"). Trick is, I am able to post the Web Service if it resides on the same server. But the moment I post the web service from a remote server or different server, I assume its as if the post data never got sent.

Below is an example of the function I use to post the webservice. Keep in mind it works on the local server, but not on any remote servers.

```
   Function HttpPostData2(sUrl, sRequest, Data)
```

set oHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
   oHTTP.open "post", sUrl & sRequest , false
   oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   oHTTP.send Data
   HttpPostData2 = oHTTP.responseText
 End Function

```
url = APIurl & "MyQuery"
```

Response.Write(url & "
")

```
params = APIKey & "MyParameter=657407"
```

Response.Write(params & "
")

result = HttpPostData2(url, null, params)
 Response.Write(result)

Comment: Solved.

<system.web>
  <webServices>
   <protocols>
   <add name="HttpGet"/>
   <add name="HttpPost"/>
   </protocols>
  </webServices>

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the variation of the XMLHTTP object your're instantiating for oHTTP.

Try this:

```
set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```